# auto adding leading zero on p:inputNumber

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to automatically add leading zeros to a `p:inputNumber` (or `p:inputMask`)

I guess if primefaces has this feature, I tried the attribute `leadingZero="allow"` explained in this [link](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2400) with no success.

I've also tried the inputMask using a kind of workaround with `slotChar`:

```
<p:inputMask id="myfield" maxlength="4" mask="9999" value="#{mybean.myfield}" slotChar="0" />
```

But when I type the numbers it behaves like a `rightPad`.
That is, when I digit "1" it renders "1000" instead of "0001".

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: What is the data type of the bean property `#{mybean.myfield}`?

Comment: @Selaron is String, because the backing bean has to keep the zeros.

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify what the expected behavior is. To me it wasn't clear that you ask for a left padding with zeros when reading `I need to automatically add leading zeros` even tho your statement `instead of "0001"` somehow implies that.